# VBscripting code grouping

Tags: vbscript

Below is a script I am working on that will return a text message to the users. I am trying to join predefined parameters together. So basically I need the results of Glasspart and Optioncode to join with the * between them and find that in the lookup table.

```
If TableLookup("Non Stock Item","(NS)",CStr(GlassPart "*" OptionCode)) then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If GlassPart and OptionCode contain simple/single values, use string concatenation (&):

```
>> GlassPart = "ABC"
>> OptionCode = 123
>> Joined = GlassPart & "*" & OptionCode
>> WScript.Echo Joined
>>
ABC*123
```

If not, describe those variables in detail (type, content).